# Paramater problem while using Entity Framework to get data from a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, api, entity-framework

My goal is to get a list of reports from my stored procedure, and return this list as JSON. I am using similar code to this elsewhere in my controller, the difference here is the stored procedure I wrote requires a parameter, and that is where the issue lies.

The error that is thrown is "System.Exception: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@DynamicCategoryId"" I have tried a few different ways to get the parameter to work, with no luck.

Here is my code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetReports/{categoryId}")]
    public string GetReports(int categoryId)
    {
        List<GetReporsResult> paramaters = new List<GetReporsResult>();

        try
        {
            SqlParameter paramCategoryId = new SqlParameter("@DynamicCategoryId", SqlDbType.Int);
            paramCategoryId.SourceColumn = "@DynamicCategoryId";
            paramCategoryId.Value = categoryId;
            paramCategoryId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            paramaters = context.GetReporsResult.FromSqlRaw("EXEC dbo.GetReports @DynamicCategoryId", paramCategoryId.Value).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paramaters);

    }
```

Interestingly, if I do ("EXEC dbo.GetReports " + categoryId.ToString() ) it works, however that is not a good practice.

Comment: parameter for `FromSqlRaw`  should be `paramCategoryId` not `paramCategoryId.Value`

Comment: That is how I had it before, but I get an error message that I am passing in the object, I verified it is not null: "'The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not SqlParameter objects.'"

Comment: That's strange as [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#code-try-4) we have usage of `SqlParameter`

Comment: Have you updated your entities from database? Make sure you have latest version of your stored procedure in entity framework.

Comment: hehe, you are using wrong `SqlParameter` class ... it is easy to find with your error: *The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not SqlParameter objects.* 1 second of googling

Comment: What is the correct SqlParamater class?

Comment: the one from different assembly

Comment: I don't know what that means

Comment: As far as my entities, I wrote them myself.

Comment: EF expects  `X.X.SqlParameter` and you are using  `Y.Y.SqlParameter` i don't know which because you didn't wrote ... problem is in the code which you didnt wrote in the question, which is `using Y.Y;`

Answer (score 0):

Never use Parameter.Value as an parameter. Check category id , it could empty.

and try this code, it was used many times in many places

```
var paramCategoryId = new SqlParameter("@DynamicCategoryId", categoryId);
 paramaters = context.GetReporsResult.FromSqlRaw("EXEC dbo.GetReports @DynamicCategoryId", 
paramCategoryId).ToList();
```

or I am usually using

```
paramaters = context.GetReporsResult.FromSqlRaw("EXEC dbo.GetReports @DynamicCategoryId", 
parameters: new[] { paramCategoryId} ).ToList();
```

Comment: I tried this and got this error: "System.Exception: 'The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not SqlParameter objects.'" so I changed it to paramCategoryId.Value in FromSqlRaw, and I got the original error again.

Comment: I tried the second option as well, same result: System.Exception: 'The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not SqlParameter objects.'

Comment: There's no need to make an array for the parameters as it's a `params` parameter

Comment: @David I am agree, this is why I gave him the first variant. I am too lazy so I am using standard array. This way I don't need to change code if I have several parameters.

Comment: But it's a `params` array so you don't change anything with multiple parameters.